# Direction Ratio of line when one of contributing plane is constant

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

A line is given by equation $$x-5=5-y, z=5$$ Is the direction ratio of the line 1,1,5?

As per my reasoning all points on the line are its direction ratio, so a,b,5 will the direction ratio provided a and b lies on the line (5 is constant and will always lie on the line as per the equation). However putting x=1 and y=1 the first equation does not satisfy i.e. is $$1-5=5-1 \implies -4=4$$ in the canonical form of line's equation i.e. $$\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}$$
we know that the direction ratios are a,b,c but I am not able to reason for the above case. Need help in understanding it both from analytical and geometrical point of view if possible.

Comment: No the direction ratios are $1,-1,0$.

Comment: Note that the equation of the given line can be written as $\frac {x-5} {1} = \frac {y-5} {-1} = \frac {z-5} {0}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the points on a line are its direction ratio only when the line goes through center.

In 2d a line is written as $y = mx+c$ , so, $(y_2-y_1)=m(x_2-x_1)$. See here the points are not direction ratios unless $c=0$. It is true for higher dimension also. In 3d we get $(z_2-z_1)=m_2(\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2})$, where $m_2$ points the angle between the line and the xy plane (as m points the angle between the line and x axis earlier). You can draw the picture and convince yourself also furthur you can derive the direction ratios from this in 3d (by putting the value of $y_2-y_1$ what we got earlier).

In your case  $x+y=10$ , so what is m here, also when $z_2-z_1=0$ what is the direction ratio for z. I mean what you need to multiply with $x_2-x_1$ to get $z_2-z_1$ here.

Let $(y_2-y_1)=m(x_2-x_1)$ and we claim that all points are its direction ratio. So then $y_2=mx_2$ and also $y_1=mx_1$ for any/all $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ that indicates $y=mx$ and $c = 0$,  conversely if $c \ne 0$, $y\ne mx$ as $y= mx+c$.

Comment: Thanks Amitava! so for $x+y=10$ we have m=-1 which makes $(y_2-y_1)=-1(x_2-x_1)$ which when plugged into the second 3d equation gives $(z_2-z_1) = m_2(x_2-x_1)\sqrt 2$ and putting $z_2 - z_1 = 0$ we get $m_2 = 0 \implies tan\theta = \pi/2$ hence direction ratio is $0$ for the z axis. However can you elaborate a bit on "points are not direction ratios unless $c=0$" in both 2d and 3d, I could not conclude this looking at the two equations you shared ($y=mx+c and .(y_2-y_1)=m(x_2-x_1)$)

Comment: @RohanFrederick please check I edited my answer.

Comment: Also can you explain what is $\tan\theta$ you wrote.

Comment: I made a mistake in $tan\theta$, $m_2=tan\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle made with the xy plane having perpendicular as $z_2 - z_1$ and base as $\sqrt {(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$ hence $m_2 = 0 \implies tan\theta = 0 \implies \theta = 0$ (here $\theta$ is angle made with xy plane) and this makes the angle with z axis as $\pi/2$. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Well in case if you do not have any more questions, you may consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: Just did, however since my reputation is less than 15, will not display publicly. Regardless really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem at all. Just check whether you can mark my answer as "most helpful" or not (i.e. the tic mark). Anyways glad to help.